# How to create light mask from image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, mask

Basically there a 3D logo png I created with another software that can't do animation nor masks (exemple: https://www.pixelslogodesign.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/sculpteo-3D-300x300.jpg). I want to use it in a video, with a transparency/light mask that can somewhat simulate reflection on the 3D logo png I have.

Is there a way in PS, to generate a mask than I can use in AE, to somewhat simulate reflection on the shape? Thanks.

Comment: Please remember that AE are used for mostly motion graphics rather than static graphics so you said you want your logo in video so if you are planning to animate mask along with logo go with AE because it have maskimg too but it'll take some practice to get habitated to mask and even Photoshop have pretty easy masking but it can't be used for animating because

Comment: Photoshop made for editing pixels instead of making animations!

Comment: Thanks. But from a static PNG of a 3D logotype, can I make it seem that it has reflection following the shape or specular information of the image?

Comment: Yes it's possible indeed. Use after effect for that. In that you can/or make a precomposition in which you can use your logo and in your main comp you can use mask in shape and then you can assin any transformation eg Transform Rotate etc.!  This should be a 5 to 10 minute work if you're familiar with AE basics :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not talking about transformation at all. I'm talking about having a specular fusion mask generated from the png to simulate moving reflection on the image.

Comment: Yeah but to **simulate moving** don't you have to apply transform keyframes?  :D

Comment: Not sure if this should be a comment or an answer, but no... you can't do what you want with just a PNG image.
If you have AE, you have access to Cinema4D lite. You could use this to actually re-create the logotype in actual 3D and then make a reflection animation in Cinema4D.